# Kotlinx datetime missing 0 in date

Tags: android, kotlin

Using kotlinx datetime i'm expecting this "11/02/22" when using this code

```
val date = "2022-02-11T07:00:00.000000Z".toInstant().toLocalDateTime(TimeZone.currentSystemDefault()).date
val newDate = "${date.dayOfMonth}/${date.monthNumber}/${date.year.toString().substring(2,4)}"
```

However, this returns

```
11/2/22
```

Is there a way to get the '0' back in the month?

Comment: Not too elegant, but `"…/${date.monthNumber.toString().padStart(2, '0')}/…"` should work. You could use `String.format` as well. I don't know if there's a formatting class in kotlin datetime so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by using [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Like below

```
val newDate = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy"))
```

Comment: thank you, although im trying to stick with kotlin datetime for now